How to sample a R8_UINT texture in hlsl？
I'm a newbie in DX12 and trying to visualize Stencil buffer onto screen. I've been copied stencil plane slice into a DXGI_FORMAT_R8_UINT texture, but when HLSL samples this texture it just returns 0, and finally my render result is a black screen.
Here is the texture info from PIX:

and the shader code is simple:
Texture2D    gDiffuseMap : register(t0);

SamplerState gsamAnisotropicWrap  : register(s4);

float4 PS_PixelOverdraw(VertexOut pin) : SV_TARGET
{
    // gsamAnisotropicWrap is a static sampler
    int diffuseAlbedo = gDiffuseMap.Sample(gsamAnisotropicWrap, pin.TexC);
    float3 litcolor = diffuseAlbedo / 255.0f;
    return float4(litcolor, 1.0f);
}

when I debug pixel history at uv coordinate (0.321875, 0.5625), it just return 0 from Sample expression:


I have a few suggestions:

Use SampleLevel() instead of Sample() to make sure that you're reading the correct mip of the texture.
Read the texture sample into a float, or even a float4, instead of an int. That way you can double check that it's not treating it as an _UNORM texture or doing something else that would give you a value that isn't an integer.
Explicitly specify which channel you want from the result of the texture sample by adding .r onto the end of the line. You should be getting a warning from the shader compiler complaining about that.
Try using a different sampler state. Maybe point filtering would make more sense than anisotropic filtering in this case?


Hi Adam, Thanks for your suggestions, problem solved by using a "Texture2D & Load" pair instead of "Texture2D & Sample".
